# Function stuck to a value (it returns but the value does not update) JS

Tags: javascript, function, return, refresh

I have a JS function that executes the following: when typing a text in the input, and pressing a button, the function analyzes the string to see if it has any of following letters: if it contains the letters "a", "b", or "c", it returns "Perfect."; if it contains "d", "e", "f", returns "Good", and so on.

It turns out that, when testing in the browser, the function works only once. If I insert a new input, just after running the function, it keeps returning the previous value.

For example: If I enter the text "ABC", it returns "Perfect"; but if, after that, I insert the text "DEF", it keeps returning the value "Perfect", when in fact it should return "Good".

```js
const textInput = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
const button = document.getElementById("btn");

const checkLetters = () => {
  for (i in textInput) {
    if (textInput.match(/a|b|b/gi)) {
      document.getElementById("resultOutput").innerHTML = "Perfect.";
      return;
    } else if (textInput.match(/d|e|f/gi)) {
      document.getElementById("resultOutput").innerHTML = "Good.";
      return;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("resultOutput").innerHTML = "Bad";
      return;
    }
  }
};

checkLetters(textInput);
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input id="nameInput" type="text" onkeyup="keyUp(event);" />
  <button id="btn" type="button" aria-label="result" onclick="checkLetters(textInput)" </button>
</div>

<div class="output">
  <output id="resultOutput" type="text"></output>
</div>
```

I came up with a solution that works on my desktop, but that fails on mobile: I inserted "window.location.reload()" inside the HTML button, so that the button refresh the browser right before executing the function. In this way, the function returns fresh and with no previous value, and works normally.

```
<button id="btn" type="button" aria-label="result" onclick="window.location.reload(); checkSyllables(catsName)"</button>
```

But this solution seems to be very brute and ugly, and I would like to solve the problem for good, right in JS, and not the way I did it (also because it doesn't work on mobile).

I appreciate any and all help! My code is probably very bad, and I could use better methods, but it was the best way I managed to do since I only start programming a month ago.

Comment: Wouldn't moving `const textValue = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;` inside the function fix it?

Comment: Running your code immediately outputs the following error : `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags`. `match(/d|e/f)` is incorrect

Comment: @JeremyThille What? How did you not get `i is not defined`?

Comment: That's just what I get when I click the "Run code snippet" button.

Comment: @MikaelsSlava Why should it throw that error? `i` is an implicit global variable.

Comment: Also @Matheus you are passing an argument `checkLetters(textInput)`, which is useless because the function definition doesn't accept any argument.

Comment: As @MikaelsSlava already said. You never update the content of `textValue`

Comment: @Andreas I did not know that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @MikaelsSlava Then forget it as fast as you can. That's just a terrible "feature" of JavaScript...

Comment: @Andreas But isn't it there for a reason? Maybe it comes with a slight performance increase or something when using instead of another variable. I mean, it would make sense since defining a new variable would take up more memory... Right?

Comment: You do not need to loop through each character of a string in order to check whether it matches your RegExp; furthermore, for your use case the `test()` method seems more appropriate than the `match()` one. Finally you can replace `a|b|c` and `d|e|f` with the equivalent ranges `[a-c]` and `[d-f]`. If you put everything together, you end up with something similar to: https://jsfiddle.net/7dpvb8sr/

Comment: ... and you have an error in your HTML: `<button id="btn" type="button" aria-label="result" onclick="checkLetters(textInput)" </button>` is missing the closing `>` for the opening tag and the button label; it should be `<button id="btn" type="button" aria-label="result" onclick="checkLetters(textInput)">check</button>` instead

Comment: `(/d|e/f)` is a typo that is not on my code. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to loop through each character of a string in order to check whether it matches your RegExp; furthermore, for your use case the `test()` method seems more appropriate than the `match()` one. Finally you can replace `a|b|c` and `d|e|f` with the equivalent ranges `[a-c]` and `[d-f]`.

If you put everything together and add a bit of separation of concerns, you end up with something similar to:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('nameInput');
const output = document.getElementById('resultOutput');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => checkLetters());
input.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => keyUp(event));

function keyUp(event) {
  // ... do stuff
}

function checkLetters() {
  const inputTxt = input.value;

  if (/[a-c]+/gi.test(inputTxt)) {
    output.innerText = 'Perfect.';
  } else if (/[d-f]+/gi.test(inputTxt)) {
    output.innerText = 'Good.';
  } else {
    output.innerText = 'Bad.';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input id="nameInput" type="text" />
  <button id="btn" type="button" aria-label="result">check</button>
</div>

<div class="output">
  <output id="resultOutput" type="text"></output>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

first things first your script is missing closing tag, this is the correct script:

```
const textInput = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
const button = document.getElementById("btn");

const checkLetters = () => {
  for (i in textInput) {
    if (textInput.match(/a|b|b/gi)) {
      document.getElementById("resultOutput").innerHTML = "Perfect.";
      return;
    } else if (textInput.match(/d|e/f)) {
      document.getElementById("resultOutput").innerHTML = "Good.";
      return;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("resultOutput").innerHTML = "Bad";
      return;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Nope, `match(/d|e/f)` is still an incorrect regex and this will still produce a syntax error.

Comment: `(/d|e/f)` is a typo that is not on my code. That is not the problem...

Comment: the syntax error was in the closing tag of the button, but about the code it is weird to not work while the logic you are implementing seems fine...